# reopen a connection on same port results in bad file descriptor handle

Tags: kdb

I have a proc which spawns a child process on port 2600. it connects to the process with handle 6, extracts some data, kills the process and then it starts another child process on the same port, I connect to it and when I try to run my commands on the handle I get this following error:

```
'Cannot write to handle 6. OS reports: Bad File Descriptor
```

The process is running and I can connect to it manually and get my data. I have a table tracking the connection and I can see the handle for the second time the child process is spawned is also 6. Any suggestions on why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: Just to make it clear. When I close the handle I send an async message to the proc with "exit 1". Could this be that the process is not killed before I open a connection to it, gets killed after that and then what I think it's the new process is just a garrbage handle to the old, now defunct process?

**UPDATE**: I do flush the handle after I send "exit 1" and the new process seem to start ok. I can see the new process running on the process (they have different names)

**UPDATE**: Even thought connection is successful the handle is not added to .z.W. so the handle doesn't appear in .z.W

**UPDATE**: found the issue. the .IPC.SCON function which I was using which i thought was just a simple wrapper for an error trap ... has logic to check a table of cached handles for the same hst:prt and take that one instead of opening another one. because my process was running on the same host:port, it was using the old cached handle instead of opening it again. thank you all for your help.

Comment: It might be worth adding an explicit `hclose handle` on the parent side after sending the "exit 1" and after flushing your outgoing asyncs

Comment: still no luck. the handle doesn't seem to be added to .z.W. might be an issue with using the same port ? maybe the port is not released in time for the new connection. Don't know yet.

Comment: I see. Are you using the vanilla `hopen` function or using some sort of wrapper/protected-eval?

Comment: for opening the connection I am using `@[hopen;x;0Ni]` where x is (host:port;timeout)

Comment: Are you sure that protected eval isn't returning null int? Are you amending the handle variable after the second call to hopen? I added another update to my reply below, could that be what's happening? I would temporarily change the above to `@[hopen;x]` for the purposes of debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of kdb are you using? Can you run the below without issues?

```
KDB+ 4.0 2020.08.28 Copyright (C) 1993-2020 Kx Systems

q)system"q -p 5000";system"sleep 1";h:hopen 5000;0N!h".z.i";neg[h](exit;0)
4475i
q)system"q -p 5000";system"sleep 1";h:hopen 5000;0N!h".z.i";neg[h](exit;0)
4481i
q)system"q -p 5000";system"sleep 1";h:hopen 5000;0N!h".z.i";neg[h](exit;0)
4487i
```

**Update:** Without seeing your code or the order of execution, it's hard to pinpoint what the issue is. If the process wasn't terminated before you attempt to start the new process, you would see an `Address already in use` error. If the process isn't up when you attempt to connect you would see a `'hop` error which means hopen failed.
Also, async messages are not sent immediately so depending on the execution order of your code, you may need to flush the async 'exit' message, but like I mentioned, if the original child process is still up when you attempt to start another, you would get an address clash

**Update 2:** As per my comment above

```
q)system"q -p 5000"; system"sleep 1"; h:@[hopen;(`::5000;2000);0Ni]; 0N!h".z.i"; neg[h](exit;1)
4365i
q)system"q busy.q -p 5000"; system"sleep 1"; @[hopen;(`::5000;2000);0Ni]; h".z.i"    // hopen times out + handle variable not amended
'Cannot write to handle 4. OS reports: Bad file descriptor
  [0]  system"q busy.q -p 5000"; system"sleep 1"; @[hopen;(`::5000;2000);0Ni]; h".z.i"    // hopen times out + handle variable not amended
                                                                               ^
q).z.W
q)
```

Comment: running 3.6 l64

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have written in your UPDATE is correct. The process is trying to connect to that port before your new process is running on it.
I think the best option would be for the newly started process to initiate the connection to the parent rather, that way you know it will be running and don't have to introduce any sleeps.
Other option is to try and reconnect on a timer, once a successful connection occurs remove it from the timer and continue with what you are trying to do.